# STM32 + Lwip, MCU load due to broadcast packet

Tags: stm32, lwip

Due to the wrong network configuration,
It is assumed that broadcast packet looping has occurred.

STM32 MCU continuously receives broadcast packets.
As a result, the MCU load increases.
Tested on the STM32F746G-DISCOVERY board,
MCU load increased to 70 ~ 80%.

In this case, the polling period is broken and
Our products do not work properly.

Except for using the Serial to Ethernet Controller with TCP / IP Protocol stack,
Is there a way to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you detect flooding of broadcast packets, you could in theory temporary disable receiving broadcast packets in the MAC configuration (the ethernet hardware inside the STM32). STM32 MCU can filter packets by broadcast, multicast, receive-all, hash of either sender or received hardward adress.